# Refactor pandas DataFrame using dates ranges

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to refactor a pandas DataFrame based on dates overlaps. To explain a bit more my problem, let me show you some examples:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'DDD'],
                          's':[date(2000, 1, 12), date(2005, 2, 25), date(2005, 8, 30), date(2009, 4, 22), date(2015, 4, 22), date(2015, 5, 7), date(1972, 11, 4), date(2019, 6, 15), date(2000, 11, 4), date(1995, 1, 1), date(1997, 1, 1), date(1998, 1, 1)],
                          'e':[date(2000, 6, 22), date(2005, 8, 30), date(2006, 1, 1), date(2015, 4, 22), date(2015, 5, 7), date(2018, 9, 28), date(2019, 8, 1), date(2019, 12, 31), date(2005, 11, 4), date(2019, 1, 1), date(1997, 3, 1), date(1998, 3, 1)]})

id      s           e
AAA     2000-01-12  2000-06-22
AAA     2005-02-25  2005-08-30
AAA     2005-08-30  2006-01-01
AAA     2009-04-22  2015-04-22
AAA     2015-04-22  2015-05-07
AAA     2015-05-07  2018-09-28
BBB     1972-11-04  2019-08-01
BBB     2019-06-15  2019-12-31
CCC     2000-11-04  2005-11-04
CCC     1995-01-01  2019-01-01
DDD     1997-01-01  1997-03-01
DDD     1998-01-01  1998-03-01
```

I would like to obtain a DataFrame such as:

```
id      s           e
AAA     2000-01-12  2000-06-22 # row unchanged: no overlap with any other row with id=='AAA'
AAA     2005-02-25  2006-01-01 # 2 rows merged
AAA     2015-04-22  2018-09-28 # 3 rows merged
BBB     1972-11-04  2019-12-31
CCC     1995-01-01  2019-01-01
DDD     1997-01-01  1997-03-01
DDD     1998-01-01  1998-03-01 # row kept as data range does not intersect with the previous one
```

Any idea on how to do that?
Hope you could help.

Regards

**EDIT**
If dates ranges for a given `id` do not overlap, rows should not be merged!

**EDIT 2**
Add a more complex `DataFrame` with several cases for data with `id=='AAA'`:

- 6 rows with `id=='AAA'`
- 1 row must be kept as-is as there is no overlap
- 2 groups must be merged because of overlaping periods

  - 1 group of two rows
  - 1 group of three rows

Comment: What if the two rows do not overlap?

Comment: Just keep both!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2: (Posting in reverse chronological order to avoid wasting reading time and unnecessary scrolling)

Tried hard to avoid a loop for OP's EDIT 2. Posting this for now. Would love to know a better solution if it exists

```
from numpy import nan
from pandas import DataFrame as df
from datetime import date,timedelta


sample_df = df({'id':['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'DDD'],'s':[date(2000, 1, 12), date(2005, 2, 25), date(2005, 8, 30), date(2009, 4, 22), date(2015, 4, 22), date(2015, 5, 7), date(1972, 11, 4), date(2019, 6, 15), date(2000, 11, 4), date(1995, 1, 1), date(1997, 1, 1), date(1998, 1, 1)],'e':[date(2000, 6, 22), date(2005, 8, 30), date(2006, 1, 1), date(2015, 4, 22), date(2015, 5, 7), date(2018, 9, 28), date(2019, 8, 1), date(2019, 12, 31), date(2005, 11, 4), date(2019, 1, 1), date(1997, 3, 1), date(1998, 3, 1)]})

def grouped_flag(row_in):
    labels = len(row_in)
    row_in['label'] = nan
    for ind,row in row_in.iterrows():
        if not row['overlap']:
            row_in.loc[row.name,'label'] = labels
            labels = labels - 1
        else:
            row_in.loc[row.name,'label'] = labels

    row_in['label'] = row_in['label'].astype(str)
    result = row_in.groupby(['id','label']).agg({'s':min,'e':max}).reset_index().drop(['label'],axis=1)


    return result


sample_df['overlap'] = (sample_df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: (x['e'] - x['s'].shift(-1)) >= timedelta(0)).reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
out_df = sample_df.groupby(['id']).apply(grouped_flag).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out_df)
```

I think this works if you're okay to not do it one step.

EDIT 1: Apologies of the cleanliness of the code. Have written this just for the solution. When replicating, do each lambda function separately on start and end date, or better yet, just write a separate function and call it in apply. That would be absolutely neat.

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from pandas import DataFrame as df, concat
>>> tbl = df({'id':['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC'],
...                           's':[date(2015, 4, 22), date(2015, 5, 7), date(1972, 11, 4), date(2019, 6, 15), date(2000, 11, 4), date(1995, 1, 1)],
...                           'e':[date(2015, 5, 7), date(2018, 9, 28), date(2019, 8, 1), date(2019, 12, 31), date(2005, 11, 4), date(2019, 1, 1)]})

## using a lambda function on the start and end date to get the min start date and max end date for each unique value in the ID column, and using concat so I can assign it to both columns simultaneously. You can do them separately in the case that it's part of a script for production/high performance.
>>> tbl[['s_mod','e_mod']] = concat([tbl['id'].apply(lambda x: tbl.loc[tbl['id']==x,'s'].min()),tbl['id'].apply(lambda x: tbl.loc[tbl['id']==x,'e'].max())],axis=1,keys=['s_mod','e_mod'])

## Since each value of id has only one unique s_mod and e_mod, subsetting the df and dropping duplicates to get the desired result
>>> tbl = tbl[['id','s_mod','e_mod']].drop_duplicates()
>>> tbl
    id       s_mod       e_mod
0  AAA  2015-04-22  2018-09-28
2  BBB  1972-11-04  2019-12-31
4  CCC  1995-01-01  2019-01-01
>>> 

EDIT 1: To account for non-overlapping dates the solution below seems to work. 

from pandas import DataFrame as df, concat
from datetime import date
from numpy import nan

sample_df = df({'id':['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'DDD'],
                          's':[date(2015, 4, 22), date(2015, 5, 7), date(1972, 11, 4), date(2019, 6, 15), date(2000, 11, 4), date(1995, 1, 1), date(1997, 1, 1), date(1998, 1, 1)],
                          'e':[date(2015, 5, 7), date(2018, 9, 28), date(2019, 8, 1), date(2019, 12, 31), date(2005, 11, 4), date(2019, 1, 1), date(1997, 3, 1), date(1998, 3, 1)]})

sample_df['s_mod'] = sample_df['id'].apply(
          lambda x: sample_df['s'].loc[sample_df['id']==x] 
           if len(sample_df.loc[sample_df['id']==x,]) == 1 # IN THE CASE THAT THERE IS ONLY ONE RECORD OF 'id' CONTAINING 'x'
           else sample_df.loc[sample_df['id']==x,]['s'].min() 
           if sample_df.loc[sample_df['id']==x,]['e'].min() # MIN END DATE OF x 
>= sample_df.loc[sample_df['id']==x,]['s'].max() # <-- MAX START DATE of x | IF OVERLAPPING ASSIGN THE MIN VALUE OF 's'
           else nan) # ELSE ASSIGN A nan
# SAME THING APPLIED FOR END DATE
sample_df['e_mod'] = sample_df['id'].apply(lambda x: sample_df['e'].loc[sample_df['id']==x] if len(sample_df.loc[sample_df['id']==x,]) == 1 else sample_df.loc[sample_df['id']==x,]['e'].max() if sample_df.loc[sample_df['id']==x,]['e'].min() >= sample_df.loc[sample_df['id']==x,]['s'].max() else nan)

sample_df
   index   id           s           e       s_mod       e_mod
0      2  BBB  1972-11-04  2019-08-01  1972-11-04  2019-12-31
1      5  CCC  1995-01-01  2019-01-01  1995-01-01  2019-01-01
2      6  DDD  1997-01-01  1997-03-01         NaN         NaN
3      7  DDD  1998-01-01  1998-03-01         NaN         NaN
4      4  CCC  2000-11-04  2005-11-04  1995-01-01  2019-01-01
5      0  AAA  2015-04-22  2015-05-07  2015-04-22  2018-09-28
6      1  AAA  2015-05-07  2018-09-28  2015-04-22  2018-09-28
7      3  BBB  2019-06-15  2019-12-31  1972-11-04  2019-12-31

# FILLING THE nan WITH THE ORIGIN VALUES SO THAT WE MAY RETAIN THE ORIGINAL RECORDS
sample_df['s_mod'] = sample_df['s_mod'].fillna(sample_df['s'])
sample_df['e_mod'] = sample_df['e_mod'].fillna(sample_df['e'])
sample_df = sample_df[['id','s_mod','e_mod']].drop_duplicates()
sample_df
    id       s_mod       e_mod
0  BBB  1972-11-04  2019-12-31
1  CCC  1995-01-01  2019-01-01
2  DDD  1997-01-01  1997-03-01
3  DDD  1998-01-01  1998-03-01
5  AAA  2015-04-22  2018-09-28
```

Comment: Great first answer! Could you please explain what each step does, or even just add comments in the code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to work for overlapping periods, but for non intersecting periods, it unfortunately fails. Seen my edited `DataFrame` in the original question.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi: Have added comments. Trust that helps. This was written as a quick fix, not something to be pasted in scripts for production. Else would have written in quite a few more steps.

Comment: @MathewGeorge, thanks for the comments. Still the issue with `DDD` and non overlaping periods exist however :) Just to be sure, how does your solution differs with @mohanys one's (below)?

Comment: Denys: Have edited for non-overlapping dates. Would not be able to handle it without non-overlapping dates without an if/else, hence a lambda would work. But for the first solution @mohanys would work.

Comment: @MathewGeorge, great answer!

Comment: @MathewGeorge, do you think there is a way to handle the case where there are more than 2 rows per `id`?

Comment: Sure @DenysBoule. Just create a normal function for the start and end date and apply them.

Comment: Thanks @MathewGeorge, but I do not understand to do what you propose. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Sure. Please do add a proper dataset that fulfills all your requirements so that the back and forth time on this question can be reduced. Happy to solve it once you update the dataset such that it resembles a good representation of your actual problem statement.

Comment: Thank you for your time @MathewGeorge. I have just added an extended `DataFrame` in the original question (see also my comments on **EDIT2**).

Comment: @DenysBoule: Tried not to use a loop, but ended up having to. If you can find a better way to assign a label, do share.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `drop_duplicate` method after you generate the `DataFrame` [Pandas DOC](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: I don't think so. ```drop_duplicates``` will not merge date ranges

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['s']= pd.to_datetime(df1['s'])
df1['e']= pd.to_datetime(df1['e'])
def f(x):
    s = df1.loc[x.index, 's']
    t = df1.loc[x.index, 'e']
    if s.iloc[-1]>t.iloc[0]:
        return s.iloc[1]
    else:
        return s.min()
df1= df1.sort_values(['id','s'])
df1['sa']=df1.groupby('id')['s'].transform(f)
df1['ea']=df1.groupby('id')['e'].transform('max')

cl=[]
dl=[]
def func(x):
    s = df1.loc[x.index, 's']
    t = df1.loc[x.index, 'e']
    u = df1.loc[x.index, 'sa']
    v = df1.loc[x.index, 'ea']
    if s.iloc[0]==u.iloc[0]:
        cl.append(x.index[0])
        dl.append(x.index[1])
    else:
        pass

df1.groupby('id').apply(func)
df1.loc[cl, 'e']=df1['ea']
df1.drop(dl,inplace=True)
df1.loc[(df1['s']>df1['sa']), 's']=df1['sa']
df1.drop(['sa','ea'], axis = 1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: this will work if 's' & 'e' are datetime objects. If they have not been converted, use `df['s']= pd.to_datetime(df['s'])` & `df['e']= pd.to_datetime(df['e'])` to convert them & then run the above code

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work if dates ranges do not overlap. Question edited

Comment: you mean to say that if two rows do not overlap? keep them both?

Comment: in your new data, for CCC, the dates in 2nd row overlap completely the dates in first row. Is this a possibility? I thought the column 's' is first row was the oldest date for each ID

Comment: I did not changed data for `CCC`, just added `DDD` data to show something with non overlaping periods. Note that I did not took care of rows order.

Comment: @DenysBoule Then consider up-voting & accepting the answer.